# Fail to use global variable to count thread

Tags: python

I was trying to use a global variable to count the number of thread.

```
l = range(1, 11)
clientCount = 0
listLock = threading.Lock()
def clientThread(conn):
    which listLock:

        global clientCount
        print(clientCount)

        clientCount =+ 1
        connectionSocket.send(bytes(str(randInt) + ' ' + str(clientCount)))
        choi = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        print('User-' + str(clientCount) + ' Random int: ' + str(randInt) + ' result: '+ choi)
        connectionSocket.close()

while 1:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    start_new_thread(clientThread,)
```

The first print got `0`.
From the second print, I can only got `1`.
What happened to `clientCount`? Shouldn't it add 1 each time?

update:
I fix the `clientCount = + 1`, but the result is still not what I want. The `clientThread` function handles multithread socket connection.

```
0
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: I think you want `clientCount += 1`, not `clientCount = + 1`. The first increments by one, the second sets it equal to positive 1.

Comment: If you had reduced your code to a minimal example, you would have found yourself that the global or thread is not the problem.

Comment: Did you change `=+` to `+=`, or did you just add a space between `=` and `+`?

Comment: @chepner Damn. I'm so careless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `clientCount` to `+ 1` in your function. You need to use `clientCount += 1` instead.

You also want to increase `clientCount` before printing it to get the correct count. Additionally, instead of manually releasing the lock (which will fail if you encounter an exception before), use the a `with` block (documentation: [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement), [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement)):

```
def clientThread(conn):
    with listLock:
        global clientCount
        clientCount += 1
        print(clientCount)
```

Comment: Hi Christian. I changed my code based on your suggestion.  I wonder why `clientCount += 1` sets global variable `clientCount` to 1 every time instead of increasing it.

Comment: I noticed you used threading.Thread(). Is it possible that something is wrong with the multithread?

Comment: Interesting. With ``thread.start_new_thread()`` I get random integers in the thousands. Since ``start_new_thread()`` is gone in Python 3 anyway, I recommend you use ``threading.Thread()`` ([relevant](http://www.healthyandsimple.com/2011/08/it-hurts-when-i-do-this/)).